# Unable to apply paging in mvc4 when using viewmodel and actionlink

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, pagedlist

Hi I have one link button. When i clicked on link button number of records will be displayed. I want to apply paging for that. I have tried as below.

Index.cshtml

```
@foreach (var group in Model.records)
{
    <tr>                    
        <td>@Html.ActionLink(@group.clientId.ToString(), "detailsbyClientId", "DocumentVerification", new { clientId = @group.clientId.ToString()},null)</td>
        <td>@group.clientName</td>
        <td>@group.Count</td>
    </tr>
}
```

This is my controller code.

```
public ActionResult detailsbyClientId(int? clientId, int currentFilter, int? page)
{
    if (clientId != null)
    {
        page = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        clientId = currentFilter;
    }
    ViewBag.CurrentFilter = clientId;
    int pageSize = 8;
    int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
    documentVerificationBAL objBAL = new documentVerificationBAL();
    int cId = Convert.ToInt32(clientId);
    List<detailsbyClientId> detailsbyclient = objBAL.detailsbyclient(cId);
    IPagedList<detailsbyClientId> pagedLog = detailsbyclient.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);

    detailsbyclientIdviewModel model;
    model = new detailsbyclientIdviewModel()
    {
        detailsbyclientId = pagedLog
    };
    return View("detailsbyClientId", model);
}
```

This is my viewcode

```
@model  PagedList.IPagedList<c3card.DAL.detailsbyclientIdviewModel>
@using PagedList.Mvc;
@if(!Model.detailsbyclientId.Any())
{
<div>
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="dataTable tableHover">
        <tr>
            <th>Corporate Name</th>
            <th>employee ID</th>
            <th>employee Name</th>
            <th>Nationality</th>
            <th>Document Type</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var group in Model.detailsbyclientId)
        {
            <tr>
                <td> @group.clientName </td>
                <td> @group.employeeId </td>
                <td> @group.employeeName </td>
                <td> @group.documentType </td>
                <td scope="col">
                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-cons" value="View Document" onclick="showDocumentData('@group.upld_Id');" />
                </td>
                <td scope="col">
                    < input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-cons" value="Approve" onclick="showDocumentData('@group.upld_Id');" />
                </td>
                <td scope="col">
                    < input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-cons" value="Reject" onclick="showDocumentData('@group.upld_Id');" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>

    @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("detailsbyClientId",
    new { page, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter, pageSize = 5 }))
    Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount
</div>
}
```

my viewmodel

```
public class detailsbyclientIdviewModel
    {
        public int upldId { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<detailsbyClientId> detailsbyclientId { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Metadata> metadata { get; set; }
    }
```

I am sending clientid to detailsbyclientid action method. How can I send `clientid` as `currentfilter` from actionlink? I am getting nullable error currently because I am not sending current filter. Let me know if I am wrong in any place. Thank you lot

Comment: Why do you need to send a value for `currentFilter` in the link in the `Index` view (that makes no sense because you are not yet filtering anything). Just make the parameter `int? currentFilter` so you can test if its `null`

Comment: Yes now control goes inside the action method and i am able to trace. However in view i am getting error in Model.detailsbyclientId.Count() == 0. Do i need to make any changes in my viewmodel?

Comment: Your model in the view is `IPagedList<c3card.DAL.detailsbyclientIdviewModel>` which does not contain a property named `detailsbyclientId` so `Model.detailsbyclientId.Count()` would throw an exception. But then you controller code does not make sense either since you return a `detailsbyclientIdviewModel` model.

Comment: The model in the view should be `@model detailsbyclientIdviewModel` and the code needs to be `@Html.PagedListPager(Model.detailsbyclientId, ... )`. And there is no reason to test for `null` because it will never be `null` - it can just be `@if (!Model.detailsbyclientId.Any()) { <div style="width: 100%; ... >... </div> } else { .... }`

Comment: How can i fix this sir?

Comment: As per my last comment :)

Comment: Either use the fully qualified name - `@model yourAssembly.detailsbyclientIdviewModel`  or add a `@using yourAssembly` statement in the view.

Comment: Sorry i did not put fully qualified name. i am getting below error 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<c3card.DAL.detailsbyclientIdviewModel>' does not contain a definition for 'PagedListPager' and the best extension method overload 'PagedList.Mvc.HtmlHelper.PagedListPager(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, PagedList.IPagedList, System.Func<int,string>)' has some invalid arguments
Am i doing wrong here?

Comment: You need to read my previous comments - it needs to be `@Html.PagedListPager(Model.detailsbyclientId, ..... )` and `Page @(Model.detailsbyclientId.PageCount, etc`

Comment: Thank you. I edited as you said i do not know why i am getting error. I put above what i tried. Is there anything i have to make changes in controller code?

Comment: Your model is wrong - it needs to be `public IPagedList<detailsbyClientId> detailsbyclientId { get; set; }`

Comment: Thank you. Do i need to change as below in view if i am not wrong? @model PagedList.IPagedList<c3card.DAL.detailsbyclientIdviewModel>

Comment: No. The model in the needs to be `detailsbyclientIdviewModel` and you need to change the model property as per my previous comment

Comment: Ok thanks a lot. I was getting error in Model.PageCount(detailsbyclientid does not contain definition for pagecount and no extension method page count accepting first argument of type detailsbyclientviewmodel) so i confused

Comment: Hi stephen. May i know why i am getting Model.Pagecount. do i need to change anything in my controller code?

Comment: Read my previous comments!! (3 back) Your model is `detailsbyclientIdviewModel` It contains a PROPERTY named `detailsbyclientId` which is the Paged List property - its that property you need to refer to - `Model.detailsbyclientId.PageCount` and `Model.detailsbyclientId.PageNumber` NOT `Model.PageCount` and `Model.PageCount`

Comment: i am really sorry i did not see. It works fine thanks a lot stephen. Can you provide answer please...

Comment: Sure thanks lot. Take care

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your parameter for `currentFilter` to `int?` (nullable), and then you can just test if its `null` or not. Not also that you link can be just

```
<td>@Html.ActionLink(group.clientId.ToString(), "detailsbyClientId", "DocumentVerification", new { clientId = group.clientId },null)</td>
```

However there are multiple other errors in your code that will throw exceptions.

First, the model your returning to the view is typeof `detailsbyclientIdviewModel`, therefore the model in the view must match

```
@model yourAssembly.detailsbyclientIdviewModel
```

Next, you are assigning the PagedList to property `detailsbyclientId` so you need to change the model to

```
public class detailsbyclientIdviewModel
{
    ....
    public IPagedList<detailsbyClientId> detailsbyclientId { get; set; }
}
```

so that it can be used by the `@Html.PagedListPager()` method.

Finally, you need to refer to that property in the pager methods

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model.detailsbyclientId, page => Url.Action("detailsbyClientId",
    new { page, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter, pageSize = 5 }))
Page @(Model.detailsbyclientId.PageCount < Model.detailsbyclientId.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.detailsbyclientId.PageCount
```

Having said that, its unclear why your passing a `detailsbyclientIdviewModel` model to the view when you never use the `int upldId` or `IEnumerable<Metadata> metadata` of that model. You could just keep the original code in your view and in the controller

```
IPagedList<detailsbyClientId> pagedLog = detailsbyclient.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);
return View("detailsbyClientId", pagedLog );
```